# Show that: $A_1A_2=R\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}}}$ , the number of square roots being $n–1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, nested-radicals

Let $A_1A_2…A_k$ a polygone inscribed in a circle of radius $R$, with $k=2^n$
. Show that:
$A_1A_2=R\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}}}$ ,
the number of square roots being  $n–1$.
This may seem a nice problem By looking at this([If $ (A_1A_2)^2 + (A_1A_3)^2.......... + (A_1A_n)^2= 14r^2$, then prove that the number of sides is 7.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854072/if-a-1a-22-a-1a-32-a-1a-n2-14r2-then-prove-that-the)) I deduced that $A_1A_{k+1}=2r\sin\Bigl(\frac{k\pi}{2^n}\Bigr)\ $ and so $A_1A_2=2R\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})$. I also observed that:

[image]

And such I deduce that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2^n})$ would give me my desired squared root. It uses the formula of the division by $2$ of the argument of a trigonometric function in reverse and it gives me what I want. However, I don't know the  inductive steps required and how to bridge my intuitive ideea to the general result in $n$. What my intuition says does not suffice. Any help, please?

Comment: Do you really mean $k=2n$ and not $k=2^n$?

Comment: See e.g. this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85225/147873

Comment: @ancientmathematician it is indeed as you observed. I have corrected

Comment: @Winther I will try to write the answer immediately.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538786/a-n-sqrt2-a-n-1-a-1-sqrt2/3538868#3538868) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449592/evaluating-the-limit-of-a-sequence-given-by-recurrence-relation-a-1-sqrt2-a/449611#449611) you will find a few useful details that will help you with the square roots.

Comment: You need the trig formulas
$$2\cos\frac\alpha2=\pm\sqrt{2+2\cos\alpha}$$
and
$$2\sin\frac\alpha2=\pm\sqrt{2-2\cos\alpha}$$ with the signs chosen according to the quadrant of $\alpha/2$. Convert a sine to a cosine of the complementary angle if/when required. Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/334796/11619).